# Text displayed twice in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

When I try to add text to p5.js canvas, it got displayed twice for some reason. Attached code below:

```js
let img;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    img = loadImage('https://mediumpurpleperfumeddegrees.boyuan12.repl.co/circuit1.webp');
    textOutput();
}

function draw() {
     image(img, screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width, 0, img.width * 1.25, img.height * 1.25);
     textSize(20);
     text('5V', screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width - 20, img.height / 2 + 30);
     text('50Ω', screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width + 100, img.height / 2 - 45);
     text('100Ω', screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width + 220, img.height / 2 + 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqbHL.png)
[p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/boyuan12/sketches/kjgIDSdTc)

I tried to look through documentation but found none too helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`draw()` runs many times per second, intended for animation. Usually, you want to clear the screen before redrawing it, otherwise you can wind up with ghost images.

You're loading the image in `setup`, which doesn't wait for the image to show up before starting the `draw()` loop. Initially, `img.width` is 1 for a few frames, then the image loads and it becomes whatever the image's width is, 200 or so. The combination of `draw()` running without clear and the asynchronous image load causes the text to show up in two places.

Instead, use `preload` to avoid drawing anything until your image is ready and either disable the animation loop with `noLoop()` or use `background()` or `clear()` at the top of `draw()` to wipe stale drawings.

```js
let img;

function preload() { // fix 1
  img = loadImage(
    "https://mediumpurpleperfumeddegrees.boyuan12.repl.co/circuit1.webp"
  );
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
  textOutput();
  noLoop(); // fix 2
}

function draw() {
  // clear() // alternative to noLoop() if you want animation
  image(img, screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width, 0, img.width * 1.25, img.height * 1.25);
  textSize(20);
  text("5V", screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width - 20, img.height / 2 + 30);
  text("50Ω", screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width + 100, img.height / 2 - 45);
  text("100Ω", screen.availWidth / 2 - img.width + 220, img.height / 2 + 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```